# Looking to group specific items from a list based on names using linq, html helper related

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, distinct, html-helper

I have a list of items I am retrieving which i wish to be grouped into divs
depending on the common name that a set of the list items may have

say for instance a list of firstnames I have.

i would like to be able to create a div dynamically based on the items common attibutes.

id 23 
fistname darren
id 37 
fistname darren
id 67 
fistname darren

id like to group all the firstnames darren into one div and any others that share common firstnames

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about htmlhelper, but the linq groupby method is simple to use:

```
var firstnamegroups = items.GroupBy(item => item.FirstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll help you with the query only, you can continue after this point with the your HTML code.

Sample Data:

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
list.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "A", ID = 1 });
list.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "B", ID = 2 });
list.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "B", ID = 3 });
list.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "C", ID = 4 });
```

The LINQ expression:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(item => item.FirstName);
```

Put here your HTML code:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    string name = item.Key;
    // Add here the div and use [name]

    foreach (var person in item)
        ;// Add here the items in the div
}
```

Good luck!